# How to organize bank accounts with wife

Tags: banking, bank-account

My wife and I are recently married, both of us are working hard. At the moment we currently have the same system as prior to our marriage. Which simply put is that both of have our own bank accounts and we split the costs between us.

We will soon be taking out a mortgage for a house. Any recommendations how to arrange our bank accounts in an intelligent system so that we can put our money together?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are essentially three ways to do this:

1. Each of you have your own bank account. Shared costs are split between you equally (or whatever proportion you want). Any money left over is yours to do what you want with. This emphasises your financial independence from each other, and becomes much less tenable if you are not both working.
2. One bank account. The traditional approach. All money is paid into it, and everything comes out of it. Both of you get to scrutinize what the other person is spending. There may need to be some negotiations around surprise gifts etc.
3. "His", "Hers" and "Ours" bank account. Most expenses come out of "Ours", but an agreed-on amount goes into "His" and "Hers" which the owner can do what they like with. Or you can agree that a fixed amount comes out of "His" and "Hers" for joint purchases, which makes it more similar to option 1.

Comment: This question seems familiar. I use your method #3. We were paid into his/hers, and transferred all but $1000 to Joint. I didn't want to worry about sharing a joint checking account that we both might mess us. 20 years, never an issue.

Comment: I can highly recommend option 3. In my opinion, it's the best of both worlds. Everybody keeps a little independance for stuff they want to buy themselves, while you still have to discuss, talk and make the "grand" finances out of the joint account work. I cannot see any downside to this.

Comment: Chiming in to say option 3 is what we use. If you both pay in 50:50 then you ensure all bills are paid 50:50 with no additional hassle (works for all ratios). It then leaves all remaining earnings as personal spending monies.

Comment: Also using Option 3. Happily married for two years. My wife and I divert $100 from each paycheck each to our personal accounts as our "mad money" to be used for clothing and games. I do suggest discussing with your spouse what to do when that money isn't enough. My wife got into a bad credit card situation at one point because she didn't want to tell me that she needed money to pay it off.

Comment: I also use option 3. The benefit of option 3 is that as circumstances and salaries change, it can remain an equitable system. For example when we had children and my wife ceased working, we had to reduce the amount that went into our 'individual' accounts - we both make sacrifices. It reflects the 'team' nature of our marriage - we both contribute to the team, it's just that the financial contribution is currently made by me. In Jan it will be 17 years of married bliss :)

Comment: I sorta like the concept of combining option #3 with allowing both parties an "allowance" which they can save or spend as they see fit, as large or small as makes sense given your expenses and retirement savings. (Since I'm in a very-long-term relationship that will probably last for the remainder of our lives without ever being a marriage, I'm currently operating under option #1... with informal loans and gifts back and forth as needed.) ... Not-entirely-irrelevant song cue: [God Bless the Child](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_1LfT1MvzI)

Comment: As a note to option 3, I find that a variant is good for single people too! Have a main "budgetted household expenses" account (comparable to the Ours account), and your own personal account that gives you a set amount per time period to use for the "because I wanna" stuff (like eating out instead of packing a lunch, etc). At the end of the time period any money left over in your personal account can be rolled into a personal savings account, which you can use for "bigger stuff that I just wanna", etc. Since trying it I worry so much less and find it easier to control expenses.

Comment: This answer kind of lacks option 4 - both partners keep their bank account(s), but all accounts are considered "ours". As in - my accounts are still associated with my name, my wife's accounts are still associated with hers. However, both of us have full access rights to each other's account, and payments/withdrawals/deposits are done from/to whichever account is most convenient. That seems the least cumbersome in terms of registering new accounts, redoing all the configuration stuff such as automatic regular transfers, notifying other parties, computing how much money goes where, etc.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If you each have full access rights to both accounts, aren't those really joint accounts?

Comment: Option 3 can also be implemented as virtual accounts in a spreadsheet if you keep a very detailed track of your finances anyway. However there are advantages to separate accounts even assuming complete access to each others' money.

Comment: @BenMiller: Not quite. Legally, and contractually, the *owner* of each account is still a single person. At least in my country, that makes an (if only organisational) difference.

Comment: We use a different method, it's like a hybrid of option 2 and option 3. It's like option 3 in that she gets her own account, but it's like option 2 in that... well, that's our only account. =)

Comment: Option 3 should be split into two different categories. First: The amount going to "His" and "Hers" is constant and the rest goes to "Ours". Second: The amount going to "Ours" is constant and the rest goes to "His" and "Hers". The first category results in financial equality, while the second does not.

Comment: My ex-wife and I used Option #2 for the whole marriage.  Even the divorce never caused trouble.

Answer (score 39):

There are different approaches, but here is what we do and what I recommend.  Now that you are officially a married couple, open a joint bank account, and eliminate your individual accounts.  There are several reasons for this.

Having a joint account promotes unity and teamwork.  When you only have a joint account, you do not have "your income" and "her income," or "your expenses" and "her expenses."  You work together in everything.  You discuss your goals and set your household budget together.  If one of you makes more money than the other, that person is no longer "worth more," because your incomes are pooled together.  If one person with a higher income has more in their account than the other person does, it can lead to envy, which you do not want in your marriage.

Having a joint account is more efficient and makes more sense.  With separate accounts, who pays the rent/mortgage?  Who pays the utilities, or buys the food?  If you have separate accounts, it takes a lot of work to worry about what is "fair" when deciding how to divide up the expenses.  With a single household budget and a joint account, you decide together what the household expenses are, and they get paid from one account.  If one of you has debt, you both have debt.  You work together to get it paid off and strengthen your financial situation in the process.

Having a joint account forces you to discuss your finances together.  Working toward common financial goals together is crucial in a strong marriage, but if you maintain your separate accounts, you might be tempted to put off these discussions until you are forced to by life circumstances.  It is better to work together from the start, and joining your finances facilitates that.

You are intending your marriage to last.  Live your financial life like you believe that you are a team for life.  If you live in a community property state, separate accounts are a fiction anyway; everything is treated as if it was pooled together in the event of a divorce.

I understand that if you are used to having your own money, it can be difficult to give up that sole control over your income, but in my opinion, it is worth it.  You will certainly hear of examples from couples who maintain separate accounts and make it work.  In my humble opinion, combining your finances completely is easier to do right.

Comment: *"...who pays the rent/mortgage? Who pays the utilities, or buys the food?"* Either one still has to take care of the "mechanics" of the transaction (whether online bill payment, mailing a check, going to the grocery store, or whatever is relevant). Perhaps ideally, **both** would: you'd sit down, go out, or whatever, together and do it; that way both have full knowledge of the finances. Having private accounts *in addition* doesn't mean the couple won't be working as a team. I think of a joint account as "household's money" and each private account as "pocket money".

Comment: This is what my wife and I do. And then we created a monthly "his" and "her" budget that we can do anything with. Some months to make sure we stay in that budget we also take it out in cash so not only can we not go over but the other person never has to know what we use it for.

Comment: Single most important item in here is: "You intend for your marriage to last". If that's really what anyone intends then this is the way to go. +1

Comment: I joined this stackexchange site just to upvote your answer.

Comment: Just a minor warning - I wouldn't eliminate your old accounts as it WILL affect your credit score. source: I'm at a credit risk consultancy working with secures and unsecured personal loans.

Comment: @ryan single most important item **not** in here is 'You intend for a happy marriage'. I just hope you don't relinquish the rest of your major independences along with your financial independence.

Comment: IMO it's a terrible idea to ONLY have joint accounts. What happens when one of you dies and the account is frozen temporarily while it goes through probate? What happens if you do split up, and one of you clears out the account from under the feet of the other one?

Comment: (FWIW, my husband and I have our own separate accounts but transfer between them freely and do not in any way treat them as "my money" and "his money" - it's all just "our money", but some of it happens to be held in his name and some in mine.)

Comment: @Vicky Joint accounts are not frozen when one party dies. So this is actually an argument for eliminating the individual accounts. Do you want half your money frozen if your spouse dies?

Comment: @MD-Tech I don't think savings and checking accounts have anything to do with credit score.

Comment: Keeping separate "pocket money" i.e. personal-expenditure accounts has a major benefit if cards are lost or stolen, or you want to take precautions against that when travelling - you can take the sole account cards with you allowing access to a limited amount of money, and leaving any cards which can access the mortgage-paying (etc.) account at home.  You are much less likely to be in a situation of having to struggle to access money to buy essential - at least with our joint account if one card is reported stolen the other is stopped as well.  This all applies to credit cards too.

Comment: @ChrisH That's not really a "joint" vs "individual" thing, that's a "don't put all your eggs in one basket" thing. If you are worried about all your money being unavailable for a short time when a card gets lost, you could open up multiple joint accounts and accomplish the same goal.

Comment: @Vicky Having joint accounts requires both parties to trust each other. If the husband and wife don't trust each other, then I agree that joint accounts will be difficult, along with many other things in the marriage.

Comment: @BenMiller that's certainly true, but I mean a significant extra benefit without the extra hassle (and possibly cost) of maintaining several joint accounts.

Comment: @BenMiller - they do, at least in the UK. to quote Experian ( www.experian.co.uk - taken from a page after logging in ) "The age of your accounts indicates lenders are likely to view you as lower risk". I also know this from personal experience in the industry.

Comment: @BenMiller: joint accounts possibly *should* not be frozen, but I experienced an extreme case where the bank took several *months* to reopen a joint account even after certificate of inheritance was there. The reason they gave was that even with a joint account they cannot be sure how much of the money belongs to additional heirs. Happened in the banana republic known as Germany...

Comment: `If you live in a community property state, separate accounts are a fiction anyway; everything is treated as if it was pooled together in the event of a divorce.`  Unless there is a prenup disclaiming this...

Answer (score 9):

My wife and I set up a shared bank account. We knew the monthly costs of the mortgage and estimated the cost of utilities. Each month, we transferred enough to cover these, plus about 20% so we could make an extra mortgage payment each year and build up an emergency fund, and did so using automatic transactions.

Other shared expenses such as groceries, we handled on an ad-hoc basis, settling up every month or three. We initially just split everything 50-50 because we both earned roughly the same income. When that changed, we ended up going with a 60-40 split.

We maintained our separate bank accounts, though this may have changed in the future.

A system like this may work for you, or may at least provide a starting point for a discussion. And I do strongly advise having a frank and open discussion on these points. Dealing with money can be tricky in the bounds of a marriage.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Option 3 from the accepted answer (His/Hers/Joint), but with one caveat (that my wife and I are finding out).

Once you have children, if your income is in the mid-range where you are not paycheck to paycheck, but are not floating in excess money either (ie, you can have a vacation, but you have to plan for it and save up for a few months to do so), the child-relative expenses begin to be a huge factor in your overall budget, such that (particularly if one partner does more of the child-related buying) it can be hard to really keep up the 3 account separation, because those child-related expenses may end up being all of one earner's paycheck.

We originally did the 3 way split, where we took rent, car, and utilities from joint (ie, each transferred a reasonable portion to the joint account to cover), and just bought groceries each occasionally such that it was generally a reasonable split (as we both shopped for groceries and both earned close enough to each other that it worked out).  But once we had kids, it ended up being very different, and we eventually had to more properly budget all of our funds as if they were basically joint funds.  While we still do have separate accounts (and, largely, separate credit cards/etc., except for one joint card), it's almost pro forma now due to the kids.

Answer (score 6):

Option three is our preferred method, and we never argue about money. First we did a budget to work out ALL monthly joint out-goings (mortgage, bills, grocery etc). Then we each agreed who would pay what into the joint or household account - at the moment, I earn more than my wife, so I pay more, but we sit down every three or four months, to see if it needs adjusting. This way, we each keep our own individual accounts private, but pay what is necessary into the household account. We also set up a joint savings account; often at the end of the month, we'll have a little extra left in the household acount, and we siphon that off into joint savings to cover future unexpected costs - looks like our tumble dryer is on its last spin cycle at the moment, for example, and the joint savings account will be able to cover the cost of replacement. it all takes a bit of administration - but, as I say, we've never had a cross word about money, so the system seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

My wife and I chose to share all bank accounts and credit cards. We did so because we realized that, over the course of a marriage, the pendulum of who is the primary breadwinner may shift repeatedly. Having one account gets us in the habit of thinking about our needs and wants together and eases any transitions that may come as one or the other of us quits a job/returns to school/reduces hours.

I should also say that this system would likely not work well if either partner has semi-compulsive spending/consumption habits. I'd recommend separate bank accounts with a joint account for your mortgage in that situation.

Comment: keep in mind, two people working out of one checkbook can be tough. The first time you both write checks that day and realize you risk overdraft, you'd consider at least one separate account. DJ's #3 is the best, IMHO.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Two people working out of **two** checkbooks (tied to the same account) would be tough, but two people working out of one checkbook is no problem, in my experience.

Comment: @BenMiller - a matter of one's own experience. As an engineer, I consider it an extra point of failure. Or at least an extra effort in communication.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer As a fellow engineer, I would consider it an efficiency. :)

Comment: We have a different solution: don't write checks (well, just rent)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer "carbon copy" checks are the only way to fly.  Before web bill pay they were better than sliced bread, and even now almost as good.

Answer (score 5):

All of these answers are great but I wanted to add one piece of advice from someone who has been married 8 years and been in various financial "situations." Have one of you (whoever the two of you feel is more organized and more financially responsible) be solely in charge of paying the monthly bills, but keep a spreadsheet or some other tracking mechanism so that the other can monitor this as well. That way if you guys ever decide to switch roles there won't be much of a learning curve.

Also, don't do three bank accounts. One or two is enough, more than that starts becoming more difficult to keep track of and if you have any sort of monthly fees on the accounts it also wastes money. My wife and I each have our own account and we get money for each other if necessary. She handles paying the bills but keeps a monthly spreadsheet that has all pertinent info. We have a number and color coding system to determine which paycheck (1st or 2nd of the month) the bill is paid in and whether it has been paid, not paid, or past due (green, yellow, red). Hopefully you don't ever have to see the red color :P

Answer (score 3):

1. Primary acct. Receive and distribute money to all other accts. For security do not permit debit cards to touch or payment pull from this account.  All joint bills paid here. Attach a savings acct and credit card to this account for accruing taxes vacation money blah blah.
   This will facilitate managing instead of storing your funds.
2. Push distributions to one or two other individual accounts on whatever basis works. Cash groceries incidentals. Debit cards here.
3. Use 1 joint credit card for cash back that is paid in full monthly.
4. Use one budget based on all funds in all accounts such as YNAB. Amounts put on credit cards are put in this budget so there is not a line item for debt payments.
5. Account propagation will make life hard and skew your view of your actual disposable income. Don't.

Comment: If you have all your accounts budgeted in YNAB, it doesn't matter how many accounts you have. As long as all income is tracked in YNAB you can transfer money to any number of off-budget personal accounts and it will be accounted for.

Comment: I agree, nullability, it's easy. I in fact have about 20 of these because I'm an idiot.

Comment: A better response: YNAB makes tracking a lot of accounts possible. I track PayPal, flexible spending accounts, kid-accounts, loans both on and off budget. If our questioner chooses to not use this tool, a very simple structure will be a good place to start. The main problem I've had with multiple accounts is in matching each to planned outflows.